# Estimate rate of memory and cpu stall

Tags: c, linux, performance, x86-64, perf

I'm trying to estimate a few things. For example I have a specific function that executes after another and I was wondering if it's CPU bound so it'd be ok to move it farther away from the function or if its cache/memory bound meaning I shouldn't move it farther and I may want to split some work.

Some things I want to know is written below. My question is what events might I want to look at in order to estimate the ratio of memory to cpu stalls? What gotchas may I want to know about for the suggested events? I'm reading through perf_event_open and it isn't easy to understand what the data is measuring. Here's my starting point

- Memory VS CPU bound (is there an easy way to know?)
- Backend stalls (PERF_COUNT_HW_STALLED_CYCLES_BACKEND, does this report per cpu or process??)
- Unique L1 data lines accessed (Is this available/possible to get?)
- Instruction count (PERF_COUNT_HW_INSTRUCTIONS)
- Cycle count (PERF_COUNT_HW_CPU_CYCLES or __rdtscp)

Comment: `__rdtscp` isn't core clock cycles, unless the CPU happens to be running at a speed close to the reference clock.  Also, serializing execution (draining the ROB) with `rdtscp` (or with `lfence ; rdtsc`) will remove the possibility of your two functions overlapping execution with each other, so `rdtscp` can be a rather intrusive timing method for looking at something small compared to the size of the CPU's out-of-order execution window (well over 200 uops).

Comment: If you're curious about scheduling something differently for better out-of-order exec, try both ways and look at overall performance, and some counters like IPC.  And I guess cache misses or things like `cycle_activity.stalls_l3_miss` to look for the CPU fully grinding to a halt waiting for data (or code) from DRAM.  I don't follow your reasoning on why it would be better to keep the second function closer if the second function is bound on memory/cache bandwidth.  If it currently gets mostly cache hits, more intervening code might evict the data and change that.